# How to Split a Range with delimiter, extract Unique values and re-Concatenate

Tags: excel, vba

I am not experienced with VBA so this problem may be due to simple non understanding. I want to write a function that can look through a range, split the cell Values in that range by looking for a new line, and then concatenate the unique values and return those.

An example of one cell in a range might look like:

```
D19-160
D19-171
D19-154
etc.
```

I want to split each one up and check if its unique and then combine all the uniques into one final cell.

I have tried using a previous function ConcatUniq and combining it with split, so it would take a series of tokens instead of a range.

```
Function SplitConcatUniq(xRg As Range, xChar As String) As String
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FullName As Variant
    Dim xDic As Object
    Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    txt = Concatenate(xRg)

    FullName = Split(txt, Chr(10))

    For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)
        xDic(FullName(i)) = Empty
    Next
    SplitConcatUniq = Join$(xDic.keys, xChar)
    Set xDic = Nothing
End Function
```

I am expecting one cell to have a combination of all the unique strings, but instead I am just getting a #Value! error. Thanks for any help or even a better way to go about this.

Comment: Have you tried looping through the dictionary and appending each key, such that `for i = 0 to xdic.count-1 // str = str & xdic.keys(i) &" "`?  I would guess that `xdic.keys` in the `join` is the problem as it may not be treating that as an array.

Comment: @T-Dakin -  What's `Concatenate()` - a user defined function?

Comment: I think they are trying to use the worksheet function. It won't work as is.

Comment: Will you be passing only a contiguous set of cells in a column or row as a range (i.e. 1D) ?

Comment: Posted a solution using a udf instead of a not disponible worksheet function (as close as possible to your OP :-)

Comment: Thank you so much T.M I added your function as a user defined one and it works now. I originally used it because I saw it in the auto-fill drop down that it shows when you type incomplete functions so I thought I could use it in mine. I guess I thought it was already a defined function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to use your unchanged example code via user defined function**

It's not possible to combine ("concatenate") range data as you did because there's no exact VBA *pendant*, but you could define a *function of your own* leaving your code in OP unchanged so far. This approach only intends to be as close as possible to your original code without making further approvements.

Note: *Take into account the known limitation of the `Transpose` method as described in the code comments below.*

```
Function Concatenate(xRg As Range) As String
' Purpose: get concatenated string from a contiguous set of cells in a column or row
'          delimited by linefeed characters - chr(10)
' Note:    accepts only contiguous data of one row or one column due to range argument
' Caveat:  known limitation of transposition: array length of 2^16, i.e. roughly 64k)
    If xRg.Rows.Count > 1 And xRg.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
   '[1] get data to variant 2-dim array
    Dim v: v = xRg
   '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   '[2] change to 1-dimensioned "flat" array
   '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ' 2 a)  transposition in case of column data creates a flat 1-dim array
     v = Application.Transpose(v)
   ' 2 b) double transposition needed only in case of "row" data
     If xRg.Rows.Count = 1 Then v = Application.Transpose(v)
   '[3] return function result
    Concatenate = Join(v, Chr(10))
End Function
```